# Android Studio 4.1.1 bypasses SDK installation on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10

Installing Android Studio (android-studio-ide-201.6953283-windows.exe) works without any issues.

On the first boot-start window is shown, however, it bypasses the installation of the SDK & proceeds straight to the Welcome screen.

This in turn causes Android Studio to give the following errors:

1. `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native` in IDE Fatal Errors window
2. The SDK-manager can be opened but is stuck on Loading.

I have the following without success:

- Install Android Studio in C:/
- Removing AndroidStudio4.1 in AppData/Local/Google
- Testing out JDK 8, 14 & 15.
- Installing SDK from zip & manually adding SDK.
- Setting ANDROID_HOME in environment variables.
- Running Wizard/Android Studio as an admin.
- Downloading Android Studio 2.3.1.0 [bundle version](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/2.3.1.0/android-studio-bundle-162.3871768-windows.exe?hl=ko) (which installs SDK, but breaks on update)
- Installing 4.2 BETA version.

At this point I'm grasping for straws, perhaps someone has encountered this issue before and can provide some guidance.

[image: start window]
[image: welcome screen]
[image: SDK Manager stuck on Loading]
[image: IDE Fatal Errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The reason to why I had these issue was because of the User folder name, which included spaces.